# Eloquent mapping API attributes to field names

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an app that sends to an API an object like this:

```
{id: 4, foo_id: 4, numberOfBars: 2}
```

The Laravel backend has a database table with fields like this:

```
id, foo_id, number_of_bars
```

I'm currently mapping the API keys to table names in an array, like so:

```
$map = [
    'id' => 'id',
    'foo_id' => 'foo_id',
    'numberOfBars' => 'number_of_bars'
];
```

and using this to create a new load of data to pass to the Eloquent model. This seems inefficient. Is there a way to do this more efficiently in Eloquent? I can't create a catch-all method because as you see some keys are in camelCase and some aren't.

Comment: Have a look at this package https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence-mappable .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49546915/4848587

Comment: Did (one of) the links solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Mappable](https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence/wiki/Mappable) extension of [sofa/eloquence](https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence) to define your mapping:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Sofa\Eloquence\Eloquence;
use Sofa\Eloquence\Mappable;

class User extends Model
{
    use Eloquence, Mappable;

    protected $maps = [
        'alias' => 'sql_field_name',
    ];
}
```

*Thanks to @Salama96*